# How to get variable from a shell bash-script section sh into a groovy-file for jenkins-pipeline?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

TLDR: How do I get a variable out of a sh section, into subsequent groovy stage to be used in a method?
(As seen in below code which doesn't work unless `${ENV1_TOKEN}`, `${ENV1_PERMIT}` are replaced with hard-coded values)
Let me know if my solutions are plausible or if I need something else entirely.
Link me any similar questions or articles with semi-comparable format to this bash-script.

```
def serviceHelper
{
    node 
    {
        docker.image(env.DOCKER_REGISTRY + "/drainage/si-base-se:latest").inside('--privileged') 
        {
            withEnv(['HOME=.']) 
            {
                stage('Build Test') 
                {
                    withCredentials([
                            string(credentialsId: 'NPM_PERMIT', variable: 'NPM_PERMIT'),
                            string(credentialsId: 'AUTHORIZATION', variable: 'AUTHORIZATION')
                    ]) 
                    {
                        sh '''
                            rm -rf node_modules                                          
                            npm config set strict-ssl false
                            npm config set registry ${NPM_REGISTRY}
                            npm config set _auth ${NPM_PERMIT}
                            npm config set always-auth true
                            npx npm@6.xx.yy install
                            
                            ENV1_PERMIT=$(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION> )
                            export ENV1_PERMIT
                            ENV1_TOKEN=$(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION> )
                            export ENV1_TOKEN
                            
                            npm run build
                        '''
                    }
                }
    
                stage('Deploy-ENV1') 
                {
                    withCredentials([
                            cfCredentials
                    ]) 
                    {
                        serviceHelper.admitterDeploy(<redacted arguments>,${ENV1_TOKEN}, ${ENV1_PERMIT})
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working with a legacy UI-program which is deployed by a groovy file somehow run by Jenkins. (pipeline config not clear)
This groovy file runs the program in a Jenkins pipeline, and I can check its console output there.
This file has a method `serviceHelper` which has a node containing a method: `admitterDeploy()`
The Node makes a `docker.image`  which creates an environment which has several stages that happen in the Jenkins pipeline.
The first stage `Build Test` checks Jenkins cloud foundry for some credentials/environment variables which are needed to continue the pipeline.
Need to get credentials `permit` and `tag` for 3 different environments: `ENV1`, `ENV2`, and `ENV3`. So 6 different strings.
Legacy program does this by running a shell bash-script to compare substrings on Jenkins (e.g. look for `ENV1`), and retrieve the string.
It uses the bash-script in the code below, credentials are successfully displayed on the console output.

After the strings are located, stage `Deploy-ENV1` uses the env-specific `permit` and `tag` values to run `admitterDeploy()`.
`permit` and `tag` are 2 arguments of `admitterDeploy`.
However, I can't figure out how to retrieve values from the bash-script shell.
I can only make `admitterDeploy` work by hard-coding in the values for `${ENV1_TOKEN}`, `${ENV1_PERMIT}`).

#### Possible solutions (none of them work yet, maybe due to syntax error):

1. Create some global variables outside `ServiceHelper` and assign their value to a shell command, e.g.

```
def ENV1_PERMIT2='';
def ENV1_TAG2='';
ENV1_PERMIT2=sh'''
echo($AUTHORIZATION <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>)
'''
```

2. Check jenkins.io Bash-script: `returnstdout`: returns standard output from the task as a string rather than being printed to the console output (build log).
   Then write code:

```
ENV1_PERMIT2=sh'''
(returnstdout:true,'$AUTHORIZATION <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>')
'''
```

3. The bash-script command `export` doesn't seem to be doing anything in the console output.
   Maybe this needs to be used somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way:

- echo what you need from shell
- capture output into a groovy variable
- split it by lines

just make sure your script is not printing anything else

```
def shOut = sh returnStdout:true, script:'''
  ENV1_PERMIT=...
  ENV1_TOKEN=...
  
  echo ENV1_PERMIT
  echo ENV1_TOKEN
'''

shOut=shOut.readLines()
def env_permit = shOut[0]
def env_token  = shOut[1]

serviceHelper.admitterDeploy(..., env_token, env_permit)
```

Comment: I see. Looks like this works for my code. I'll post my answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I got my code working.
Here's the code that successfully worked for me:

```
def serviceHelper

node 
{
    docker.image(env.DOCKER_REGISTRY + "/satellite/ci-base-se:latest").inside('--privileged') 
    {
        withEnv(['HOME=.']) 
        {
            stage('Build Test') 
            {
                withCredentials([
                        string(credentialsId: 'NPM_AUTH', variable: 'NPM_AUTH'),
                        string(credentialsId: 'AUTHORIZATION', variable: 'AUTHORIZATION')
                ]) 
                {
                    sh "rm -rf node_modules && \
                    node --version && \
                    npm --version && \
                    npm config set strict-ssl false &&   \
                    npm config set registry ${npmRegistry} && \
                    npm config set _auth ${NPM_AUTH} && \
                    npm config set always-auth true && \
                    npx npm@6.14.13 install && \
                    npm run build"

                    def block = ""
                    block = sh returnStdout:true, script:'''
                        env1_token=$(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>)
                        env1_permit=$(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>)                 
                        echo $env1_token
                        echo $env1_permit
                    '''

                    block = block.readLines();
                    ENV1_TOKEN = block[0];
                    ENV1_PERMIT = block[1];
                }
            }

            stage('Deploy-ENV1') 
            {
                withCredentials([
                        cfCredentials
                ]) {
                     serviceHelper.admitterDeploy(<redacted arguments>,ENV1_TOKEN, ENV1_PERMIT)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One problem that I realized late, was that my bash-script had whitespace-characters around the assignment operators. It looks like bash-script considers whitespace-characters to be an error and breaks the script.

So I was writing:

```
env1_token = $(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>)
```

Instead I needed to write:

```
env1_token=$(echo <code to get string from AUTHORIZATION>)
```

Thanks for the reply.